# Using Map multiple times in one command

Tags: functional-style, map

Is there a way to reproduce the effect of

```
Table[i ** j, {i, list1}, {j, list2}]
```

using Map instead of Table?  Specifically, I want to write something along the lines of

```
#2 ** #1 & /@ list2 & /@ list1
```

but tell Mathematica that the first Map (`/@ list2`) should map `list2` into `#1` and the second Map (`/@ list1`) should map `list1` into `#2`.  In other words, I basically want Mathematica to evaluate the first Map (`/@ list2`) like this:

```
temp = {# ** list2[[1]], ..., # ** list2[[-1]]}&
```

and then evaluate the second Map (`/@ list1`) and return

```
temp /@ list1
```

which should be equivalent to the Table command above.

Comment: `Outer[NonCommutativeMultiply, list1, list2]`. `Outer` is the best.

Comment: I believe @march's is the right one. Just in case you could also get something similar with `f @@@ Tuples[{list1, list2}]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you insist on using `Map`, then you can nest it using its explicit form, as

```
Map[Function[t, Map[t ** # &, list2]], list1]
```

where you have to use an explicit [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) call to avoid the confusion you note.

... but as mentioned by [march](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/29734/march) in the comments, the natural way is to use [`Outer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html), as

```
Outer[NonCommutativeMultiply, list1, list2]
```

Another clean alternative is to use [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html) and [`@@@`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html), as

```
NonCommutativeMultiply @@@ Tuples[{list1, list2}]
```

as pointed out by [belisarius](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/193/belisarius), which will yield a flat list.

Comment: I think you have list1 and list2 in the wrong spots. I think you meant `Map[Function[t, Map[t ** # &, list2]], list1]`

Comment: @Jack Good catch, thanks.

Comment: Thanks!  The explicit function call with specified argument was what I needed.  I need to use Map instead of Outer or Tuples because I actually need to do further, more complicated manipulations within the inner Map than just a direct product type operation.  I should have known better than to try to simplify my problem in my post instead of presenting exactly what I needed!

Comment: @tparker There is another one : `Distribute[NonCommutativeMultiply[list1, list2], List]`

Comment: @tparker If you want to do some "more complicated things within the inner Map", I understand you want to apply some function to list2 elements ? In that case you can use these forms : `Outer[f[#1, g[#2]] &, list1, list2]` or `f[#1, g[#2]] & @@@ Tuples[{list1, list2}]` or `Distribute[f[list1, g /@ list2], List]`. Try these general examples replacing `f` by `NonCommutativeMultiply` and let set `list1 = {x, y, z}; list2 = {a, b};`. Is that what you meant ?